# opacity problems with subview

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a subview which I want to be entirely opaque.  It contains a UITextView and a UIButton which are not opaque.  The UITextView has some animation.  I don't seem to be able to get the subview to be opaque. No matter what I try it ends up being transparent.  I tried having another wrapper subview, but that didn't solve the problem.  How can I get this subview to be opaque?

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: changig transparent for view use alpha values for views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest restructuring the views so that the view needing transparency (with it's own subview tree is a sibling to a container view around the components which should be opaque.

```
main_view
 `-semi-transparent_container
   `-some_semitrans_component
 `-opaque_container
   `-some_opaque_componenent
```

Comment: Well, this isn't really a solution to my problem, but it is what I ended up doing.